# Installed TeamSpeak 3, won't open. 14.04

Tags: gnome-terminal, sh, teamspeak

I installed Ubuntu yesterday, and I still struggle with a couple of things but I'm getting used to it. I want to install TeamSpeak 3 to talk with my friends, but I just can't make it like people do on other websites or video tutorials.

Installed it successfully with the Terminal, and put it on my Desktop. Now, when I try to run the `ts3client_linux_amd64`, it won't load up. I have seen on the interwebz, I have to open the `ts3client_runscript.sh` in the Terminal, but I get an error:

[image]

I hope there is a solution.

Answer (score 1):

That is not how to run the file in the terminal. Drag and drop the .sh file into the terminal and then press enter.

Answer (score 0):

You can install ***TeamSpeak3*** in Ubuntu 14.04 using [**ppa:logan/arb**](https://launchpad.net/~logan/+archive/ubuntu/arb) repository.

You dont need to implement difficult compilation methods.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:logan/arb

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install teamspeak-client
```

Comment: http://prntscr.com/4sn5nq